# Is it okay to ask about $$$?

Tags: support, scope

**First question:** I dont' know if this is an okay place to ask about what is fair compensation for GIS work? If not, is there a better place to do this?

**The real question (gory detail)**:
I am a GIS cartographer and I work for myself. Typically, I work and bill for projects on an hourly basis. Recently however, a law firm asked me to do some GIS research and prepare a map exhibit for a lawsuit. Apparently in the legal world things work differently, and since I don't know how much time it will take, they offered to pay me a flat fee for the detective work, but I have no idea how much is reasonable or fair to ask for? I know lawyers make a lot of cheddar, so using my standard hourly rate might be doing a disservice to myself? Does anyone have experience in this arena that could offer some advice?

Comment: you will get opinions based answers. been there with freelance work, either agree a flat fee or hourly rate (capped).

Comment: Do you mind me asking what was your experience? like... how much would you ask for as a flat fee from a law firm?

Comment: I tried to provide a quantitative answer to a similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/228322/8104

Comment: You could also try Freelancing Stackexchange https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the questions you wish to ask would be fine to ask in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) but I do not think them suitable for here in Meta because they are not about the workings of the GIS Stack Exchange.

If you have not bookmarked chat in your browser you can find it via the interface too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I wasn't entirely sure where to find the GIS Chat Room? I posted the same question on Reddit and got some good feedback: [link] (https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/9ugth9/is_it_okay_to_ask_about/)

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo - I was looking for that nav panel but couldn't find it!!

Comment: @JustinKray, as PolyGeo mentioned, the Chat room is a suitable place to ask that sort of question, however, our chat room isn't very active. I think your decision to post to Reddit was a good one, as it's a lot more flexible for the types of questions you can ask there.